# "Quit and restart" control code?

Tags: zsh, tmux

I find myself frequently (after making some change to source) "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>;<kbd>↑</kbd> ing" to restart the program with changes.

Is there a way to do this more quickly, without wrapping the program in a loop and just exiting each time?

Comment: Use `kill` command to end the program.

Comment: @ryekayo ? Tmux you mean? I'm talking about killing and restarting a program I've written, inside tmux.

Comment: Ok, with tmux running, can you run `ps` and see if the program is listed in `ps`? For example: `ps aux | grep 'programName`

Comment: @ryekayo Yep, it is.

Comment: Ok so you can use a `kill` command to end the process and that should end the program you are running...

Comment: @ryekayo okay (I thought you meant `tmux kill` before) but that will make my flow slower, not faster. With Ctrl+c I can keep focus on the shell running process (debug logging).

Comment: That's three keystrokes. You aren't going to be able to improve much on that if you aren't willing to do some preparation either.

Comment: @Gilles What makes you think I'm unwilling to do some preparation? I'm posting here about it aren't I? I only mentioned not wanting to wrap it in a while loop as feels a bit too hacky, and doesn't allow 'totally' exiting. Sure I could add some other condition to it to solve that - but I guess my question here is "is there a neat built-in way?"

Comment: You stated you didn't want a loop, and that's the obvious preparation. You want to do something again and again: the natural tool for that is a loop. Avoiding a loop here is hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use loops your choices are limited as it essentially precludes just automatically restarting you program again and again.

Still you can at least cut out the step with <kbd>↑</kbd> by using the `accept-and-hold` widget. This runs the current command line (just like `accept-line` which is usually bound to <kbd>Enter</kbd>) but also pushes it onto the buffer stack, so that it is automatically pulled on the next prompt (effectively, the command remains on the prompt after execution). By default it is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> in *emacs* mode but it can be bound easily to another shortcut. For example for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (because <kbd>F</kbd> is just above <kbd>C</kbd>:

```
bindkey "^F" accept-and-hold
```

So you just have to start you program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to stop and restart it.

Comment: That's neat thanks! I'm not dead against loops, but this solves the reason I was wary of one -- it allows me to keep the option to quit and *not* restart.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from using a control code to manually restart, you might consider using a system which is specifically designed to automate this kind of procedure, that is, (re)starting a process after code changes, such as [watchman](https://github.com/facebook/watchman).

You could also use `inotifywait` (from inotify-tools) to notify when a file representing source code changes, and send a signal when it does.

(Disclosure of conflict of interest: I work at Facebook, but not on the watchman team.)